# How i can enable separate Sidekiq queue for Delayed Mailer

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using sidekiq for background job, for a different type of jobs we using different queue, eg for payment-related jobs we using critical payment queue, We using sidekiq delayed mailer extension for sending mail, its using default queue.

I want to move all mailers to a separate queue.
I try the configuration

```
config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name = 'mailer_test'
```

but after flush and restart application still pushing to default queue.
How I can move it to a separate queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That config item is for Active Job mailers. You are using Sidekiq. Put this in your initializer:

```
class Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer
  sidekiq_options queue: 'mailer_test'
end
```

Then make sure you start Sidekiq with that queue:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer_test -q default
```